# How to detect malicious scripts and prevent registration?

Tags: forms, registration, detection

today just a general question about preventing scripts to register on my site.

I've got five different registration form for different services and recognized a significant growth of fake registrations. These registration are obviously performed by scripts. Thats why I'm searching for mechanism for detecting scripts in my form and than preventing them to register to my site.

All the forms are written in Java, so I use JSPs as frontend. To use captchas isn't an option, while there are good OCR-technics to hack them. My form basicly consists of 5 input-fields with validation for valid address and email. But if a script uses a standard address (e.g. Springfield, 10 Mean St) and an emailaddress like yxz123@gmail.com it is possible to succeed.

**Known technics:**

- time to fill out all field: every human being needs at least 30 sec. to fill out, everything with less than 30 sec. is a script
- hidden form field: a standard script scans a website for form field and posts some garbage into them, a human being never would fill in values in hidden form fields, a script would do this

**More possibilities for script detection?**

These technics arn't that save and only mark another obstacle for scripts. But are there further technics to detect and avoid scripts?

I really look forward to your experienced and creative answers. :)

Thanks ahead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use a capacha that makes users click in a circle that is broken. while there are other ciomplete circles on that page.
i'ts a one click validation.

You can also let them click in the bigest circle that has a certain color

Comment: There is a nice captcha which is like the iPhone-Slider. It's intuitiv, fast and maybe even fun for the user. But its to obvious on what the script is not allowed, I like to detect the script on specific properties or behavior, than let them think the registration is successful but when using the account it's not available (or sth. like this). If you show your walls some bored scriptkiddies are able to find a way to jump over it..

Answer (score 1):

Annoying the users with some form of captcha is the only way, imo.

> time to fill out all field: every
>   human being needs at least 30 sec

So what's to stop the script from slowing down ?

> hidden form field: a standard script
>   scans a website for form field and
>   posts some garbage into them, a human
>   being never would fill in values in
>   hidden form fields, a script would do
>   this

If the script writer has the time and skill to use `OCR`, I think he can manage to avoid populating hidden fields.

Use a captcha. Don't use a standard one, use something funny like: `3 * 7 = ??` or stuff like that.

Comment: isn't the calculation captach standard? What if there is someone with dyscalculia? I didn't see the problem to put the right answer in it, in my point of view to find the solution is one of the easiest things scripts can do. You don't need to skilled to use an OCR, there are ready to use scripts and everyone can use it.